# Расставить операторы между числами чтобы получить значение Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно расставить операторы между num = 99999 - чтобы получить например number = 100. (num,number) могут быть разными. Что я сделал.

```
import itertools
from itertools import zip_longest

num = 99999
number = 100
mat_zn = '+-*/'

list_mat_zn = list(mat_zn)
list_num = list(str(num))
iter_mat_zn = list(itertools.product(mat_zn, repeat=len(list_num)-1))

res = []
for zn in iter_mat_zn:
    res.append(list(zip_longest(list_num,zn)))
```

Получил res, укорочен.

```
res = [[('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', None)], [('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', '-'), ('9', None)]]
```

Дальше пока теряюсь. Теперь нужно каждый i из res превратить в формулу. Избавившись от None(это не проблема)
Можно через перегрузку операторов в классах, но я там не силен. Еще через operator может быть еще?
Какие еще варианты есть более правильные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import product, chain, zip_longest

N = 99999
tgt = 90
nstr = str(N)

for var in filter(lambda expr: eval(expr) == tgt,
                  map(lambda ops: ' '.join(chain(*zip_longest(nstr, ops, fillvalue=""))),
                      product('+-*/', repeat=4))):
    print(f'{var}= {tgt}')  # -> 9 + 9 + 9 * 9 - 9 = 90 ...
```

Немного комментариев к коду, не являющемуся образцом читаемости.

В первую очередь сделан упор на использование генераторных выражений (`product, map, filter`) для ухода от материализации всех промежуточных значений.

Описание самого процесса:

1. `product` генерирует все возможные комбинации арифметических знаков.
2. `map` передает в лямбду каждую комбинацию, где она "сшивается" (`zip_longest`) со строковым представлением набора чисел (операндов).
3. В лямбде фильтра происходит выполнение выражения и сравнение с искомым значением.

Comment: Это круто что Вы сделали, спасибо конечно. Осталось это все понять и уложить в голове. Я одно понял что мой способ дальше не пойдет, я не туда загнул... ну и repeat=len(nstr)-1) можно сразу.

Comment: @RomanBit вы все делали правильно. Просто нет необходимости хранить в списках все возможные комбинации, полученные выражения, когда нужны только те, которые удовлетворяют условию. Да, и параметр `fillvalue=""` в `zip_longest` решает проблему избавления от `None` при последнем операнде.

Comment: Вы меня поддерживаете, спасибо. Но я не пойму как в моем случае посчитать [('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', '+'), ('9', None)] ну чтобы превратить в 9+9+9+9+9 = 45 и тд по всем i из res в цикле. Вывести те которые нужно это уже детали.